# How to set an NSArray in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm wondering why there is a -arrayForKey: method, but no -setArrayForKey: method. How could I set that array?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use `setObject:forKey:`. I guess the reason that there's a special `arrayForKey:` and `dictionaryForKey:` etc. is that you get better type safety and don't have to cast. If you use these methods and the element in the defaults does not match the type, then `nil` is returned.

Comment: Note that the -arrayForKey: etc. methods do give you one extra feature. If the object in the defaults of an unexpected type (e.g. a string, perhaps entered directly by the user), it will be ignored, and nil returned.

Comment: That's what the last sentence was supposed to mean :).

Answer (score 5):

`arrayForKey` and `dictionaryForKey` are getters. Use `setObject` to set an array.

Answer (score 2):

`- (void)setObject:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName`

This allows one to set any typical plist object, including an NSArray.

arrayForKey appears to just be a convenience method.