# Can NSUserDefaults hold a NSArray with custom objects?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

The title pretty much explains it. Do I need to serialize the objects first, or is it possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to code/decode the objects in your object (which is in your array) with  and archive the array to NSData.

Just add

```
<NSCoding>
```

to the Class of your Objects (in your array) and follow the warnings of your compiler :D

Then archive your array like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourArray];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:data forKey:@"yourKey"];


NSArray *array= [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[defaults objectForKey:@"yourKey"];
```

Check this out http://soff.es/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding

Comment: don't forget [defaults synchronize]

Comment: It is not saving Integer value

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize it.

From apple documentation for NSUSerDefaults:

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData. For more details, see Preferences and Settings Programming Guide.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.

Check for your answer here:

> [How to set an NSArray in NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342334/how-to-set-an-nsarray-in-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible,just you have to take care of NULL values while storing & retrieving it,